# Making iostat show both sectors and kilobytes read

Tags: performance, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running iostat -d -x on redhat enterprise 6.1 (over vmware, if that makes a difference), and I want to see reads and writes both in sectors and in kilobytes, but only seem to be able to display one of these at a time. That is to say, the output headers I want would look like:

```
Device: rrqm/s wrqm/s r/s w/s rsec/s wsec/s rkB/s wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz await svctm %util
```

But if I'm running just iostat -d -x, I get

```
Device: rrqm/s wrqm/s r/s w/s rsec/s wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz await svctm %util
```

And if I'm running iostat -d -x -k, I get

```
Device: rrqm/s wrqm/s r/s w/s rkB/s wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz await svctm %util
```

Is there any option I can use to get both at the same time?

Comment: There's no real point to do this, considering measuring data in sectors or kilobytes still measures the *amount* of data being transferred - and it's **trivial** to convert back and fourth yourself.  I would advise **against** using sectors read, since sector size is not guaranteed to be consistent across different hardware (albeit we all know it usually will be).

Comment: I need it in that format for software that expects all the given fields... I already have a script modifying the format slightly, I could add it to that, but I'd rather get it straight from the source and not risk new bugs.